# Why do certain objects shine only in certain light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics

I understand that wavelength is inversely proportional to index of refraction, which causes dispersion of light (red visible light is deflected less than purple), and total internal reflection.

Is there a way to explain, based on these concepts why red objects (as seen in white light) absorb most light other than red light, which gets reflected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, red objects are typically red not based on the index of refraction.  Usually such an object will absorb light in the yellow-green-blue part of the visible spectrum leaving the color red.

The index of refraction, strictly speaking, is a complex valued function and the real part is what gives rise to the things like total internal reflection, which the imaginary part gives rise to absorption.

This being said, it is possible to create a filter using thin film of alternating indices of refraction that will only allow the color red to transmit through it and reflect the other colors.

Perhaps you can clarify your question based on the above.

Comment: Why do certain objects absorb certain light?

Comment: Atoms, or molecules, absorb certain wavelength of light based on their energy levels that electrons, or other modes, can achieve.